# Understanding require in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metasploit

I was told when using `require` like below

```
require 'path1\path2'
```

Ruby will look for the specified file in `$Load_Path($:)`.

But After I read the book `Mastering Metasploit` by `Nipun Jaswal`. And It says

> ...the require 'msf/core' statement is used to include a path for all the
>   significant core libraries. These core libraries are located at the
>   core directory under /lib/msf ...

The code mentioned in there looks like below.

```
require 'rex/proto/http'
require 'msf/core'
class Metasploit3 < Msf::Auxiliary
  ...
end
```

In my understanding. The book says `require msf/core` will look for some files (not single file) to load.

I also read the [manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require).I didn't found any read says require to a path will load multiple files. Did I understand right ? Thanks.

Comment: seems like `core.rb` is requiring a lot of files : see https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/HEAD/lib/msf/core.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` only loads a single file, but there's nothing stopping that file from loading other files, which is what is happening here.